# game development - in-game resource management design

Tags: hibernate, game-engine, distributed

I've been working on a multiplayer distributed game for the last few weeks and getting the infrastructure (username/password/auth, sub/observer etc) in place

now it's just about getting to the time where I am trying to figure out spawn rates... I have three levels of upgrades for every 'base' unit (about 15). and 45+ sub-units. I am thinking about designing it so that you need some basic 'base' units and certain number of sub-units to upgrade to the next level (of a particular base-unit). I am having a hard-time figuring out how I should weigh it so that it's a semi-difficult game.. I don't want to make these static but I was wondering if there is an semi-easy way to determine this. If anyone can point me in the right direction i would appreciate it

Comment: your question is too broad... try to narrow it down a little

Comment: Make it tunable, then play the game and adjust up or down to get it the way you want.

Comment: yea that's what I was thinking.. or have some process running in the background that changes spawn rates just to make things difficult...